# Sonarqube Return a copy of "myList"

Tags: java, sonarqube

I have the following code:

```
private List<String> myList ;
private void init() {
    myList = new ArrayList();
}

public List<String> getmyList() {
    return myList ;
}
```

Sonarqube gives me the folloing msg:

```
Return a copy of "myList"
```

Question: Do I really need to create a copy of myList or how to deal with this? Should I close it like false positive?

Comment: It depends on the class design. SonarQube complains because we leak internal fields (i.e. `myList`) to the outside, permitting the calling side to modify this list. Depending on the design, this may be desired, or it may not.

Comment: hmm I tried to create new list and return it but in this case sonarqube says that there is no need to create new object or something like this :)

Comment: everytime when "sonarcube says something..or so", it has also a description as non-/compliant examples! ;)